# Convert "=" separated values file to ":" json file

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

Trying to read .env file and convert it into to json file.

Input:

```
os=amazon-linux
region=ap-south-1
```

Desired ouput:

```
{
"os": "amazon-linux",
"region": "ap-south-1"
}
```

I am trying to use jq but getting 2 problems -

1. Handle to empty lines - `jq: error (at .env:1): null (null) only strings can be parsed`
2. Handle commented line - `#this is comment` => `"#this is comment": null`

Note: .env file is not nested value file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `capture` to grab the parts by regular expressions (lines not matching would be ignored altogether), and `from_entries` to construct the object:

```bash
jq -Rn '[inputs | capture("(?<key>[^=]+)=(?<value>.*)")] | from_entries'
```

```json
{
  "os": "amazon-linux",
  "region": "ap-south-1"
}
```